# Using ptolemy’s theorem i know that one diagonal is equal to the sum of the missing sides. What is the value of the missing sides?

Tags: geometry

cyclic quadrilateral containing an equilateral triangle. I know that using ptolemy’s theorem the one diagonal is equal to the sum of the two missing sides. What is the value of the missing sides?

[image]

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Please read this text about [how to ask a good question](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question).

Answer (score 1):

Let the sides be $x$ and $(57-x)$. Apply cosine rule on the triangle with missing sides and solve for $x$.

Comment: (+1) Maybe the OP missed the fact that the upper angle is 120 degrees.

Comment: But the sides have different lengths.

Comment: @dodoturkoz Yes, maybe.

Comment: @MoniqueWilliams I am referring to the triangle with the missing sides and angle $120^{\circ}$.

Comment: Yes i do know that the upper angle is equal to 120 degrees. Still don’t know how to find the missing sides though

Comment: How would i go about the cosine rule?

Comment: @MoniqueWilliams Write down the formula for cosine rule for that upper triangle. You'll get a quadratic in $x$ which you can then solve.

Comment: Thanks so much..

Comment: The cosine rule does not work

Comment: The quadratic you'll get is $x^{2}-57x+\left(57^2 -50^2\right)=0$. Solve this and you'll get two values for $x$. $x$ is less than $57$ so the smaller root would be your answer.